# C++ displaying 2 triangles using triangle lists in directx 11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am having a bit of an issue where i want to make a triangle list display 2 triangles. I am not sure what I have done wrong but it only displays the first triangle and not the second.
Please help

```
    static const Vertex s_vertexData[6] 
{
    { { 0.0f,   0.5f,  0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },  // Top / Red
    { { 0.5f,  -0.5f,  0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },  // Right / Green
    { { -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },   // Left / Blue
    { { 1.0f,   0.5f,  0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },  // Top / Red
    { { 1.5f,  -0.5f,  0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },  // Right / Green
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }   // Left / Blue  
};


D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( Vertex ) * 4;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
InitData.pSysMem = s_vertexData;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;


// Set vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof( Vertex);
UINT offset = 0;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

// Set primitive topology
g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
```

Comment: Plz add the code, not screenshot.

Comment: ByteWidth is wrong, only 3 vertices.  You need at least 4 vertices to draw 2 triangles.  By the way, we prefer cut and pasted text to bitmaps around here, It would be nice if you pasted your code for all to see.

Comment: I changed the byteWidth to 4 instead of 3 but it still has the same result

Comment: Have you tried with 6? The actual amount of data you have?

Comment: yes that didnt work either

Comment: ``bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(s_vertexData);`` is what you actually want for that. There could be numerous other reasons why it doesn't draw. Turn on the debug device, looking for output window messages, and go step-by-step. Make sure are setting all the state objects and not assuming default values. Graphics debugging is not trivial. Where are you setting the input layout, the vertex shader, the pixel shader, etc.?

Comment: Also, what type is ``g_pVertexBuffer``? If you are using a raw pointer it probably works, but you have to be careful using the ATL ``CComPtr`` which ``&g_pVertexBuffer`` means the same thing as ``g_pVertexBuffer.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()``. Best option is to use the WRL [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).